# Match last group within _()_ with regex in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to extract the last occurrence of a substring enclosed in `_()_`, e.g.

```
'a_long_(abc)_000' => abc
'a_long(string)_(def)_000' => def
'a_long_(string)_(abc)_blabla' => abc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match using `/_\((.*?)\)_/` and grab the last match:

```
>> 'a_long_(string)_foo_(abc)_blabla'.scan(/_\((.*?)\)_/)[-1]
=> ["abc"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Smth like this:

```
str[/.*_\((.*?)\)_/,1]
```

Comment: You might want to change the `+`'s to `*`'s, otherwise this fails on `_(foo)_` and `foo_()_`.

Comment: @marcog, yes, I always do this mistake, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the regex:

```
.*_\((.*?)\)_
```

[**See it**](http://www.rubular.com/r/XAIbGvkE0b)

Answer (score 0):

This this:

```
\(([^\)]+)\)_[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

`$1` should be your string